# How to call function onClick event using ajax?

Tags: javascript

This is the piece of code working and get ajax response suceessfully but onclick not working,

```
     $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://localhost:3000/insert",
            data:data3,
            success:(data)=>
            {
                 let  table = '';
                 for(let i=0; i < data.length; i++)
                  {
                     table +=`<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                      onclick=myFun(${data[i].email})>Click</a></td></tr>`;                        
                  }
                   document.getElementById("users").innerHTML=table;
               },error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                alert('text status '+textStatus+', err '+err)
                console.log("err")
            }
    })
})    '
const myFunc=()=>{
                 alert("working") 
                 }
```

Whereas following is working,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=myFun()>Click</a>
```

Comment: its spelling mistake i know read code properly how to call function?

Comment: What about it isn't working? Is html not being added to the page, is the function simply not being called, are you getting error messages in the console? Provide a [mcve], and what does AJAX have to do with this?

Comment: add ; to this line document.getElementById("users").innerHTML=
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=myFun()>Click</a>';

Comment: get error in console : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Then you have syntax error in your code, find the line it references and fix it

Comment: Error message please

Comment: my code is proper no any bug,,,,using this get error in console : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

Use a delegated event handler bound to the container :

html codes :

```
<span id="users"></span>
```

javascript codes :

```
document.getElementById("users").innerHTML=
'<a href="#" class="click-me">Click</a>';


document.querySelector('a.click-me').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  console.log(11)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

function myFun()
{

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'file_product.php',
        data: "param1=" + param1,
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });
```

}

Comment: i get response using ajax:                                                                                  
                  success:(data)=>
                     let  table = '';
                     for(let i=0; i < data.length; i++)
                      {
                         table +=`<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=myFunc(${data[i].email}) class="btn btn-info">X</a>`</td></tr>`}
                       document.getElementById("users").innerHTML=table   in this codition code onclick not working

Answer (score -1):

It works for me,

```js
let  table = '<table>';
for(let i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    table +='<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=myFun(' + i + ')>Click</a></td></tr>';                        
}
table += '</table>';
document.getElementById("users").innerHTML= table;

function myFun(){
  console.log('my func');
}
```

```html
<div id='users'></div>
```

Comment: you may miss starting single quote in concatenate table variable `table +='<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=myFunc(${data[i].email}) class="btn btn-info">X</a></td></tr>'`

Comment: remove ES6 code add like this `table +='<tr><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                      onclick=myFun("' + data[i].emai +'")>Click</a></td></tr>'; `

Comment: is the table appended to user element?